# How to install WebTwain in React Electron Boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, electron, boilerplate, dynamic-web-twain

I dont know how to put ResourcesPath correctly. Or there is another issue.

I get this error :

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/Resources/src/dynamsoft.webtwain.css?t=20230105181423' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.